# Does a literal value has the same size of a variable with it same type?

Tags: java, variables, types

In Java, a variable of type "int" has the size of 4 bytes. If instead of making a variable, I type the literal value (for example: 57), does that literal value have the same size as a variable of type "int"?

Comment: Literals may not occupy any space at all! For example in `x = x + 1;` there is a good chance that there is no `1` in memory that is being added to `x`. It will compile down to an `increment` instruction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does java store literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434404/how-does-java-store-literals)